# How to check in new project with tfs and intellij?

Tags: tfs, intellij-idea, checkin

I use IntelliJ 13.1.1.1 and TFS when I try to check in a file with changes it say that there are no changes. Then I need to do a rollback and then check in and in most cases it works and the file gets a little gray lock icon.

When I try to check in all the project or rollback it doesn't work and say "no changes".

How can I check in all the project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to View > Tool Windows > Changes.
2. Look at the "Local" panel in the "Changes" window.
3. Right-click (or manage...) the "Unversioned Files" node, and select "Add to VCS" from the pop-up menu.
4. Right-click again, and select "Commit Changes". Done.